# Unable to Mock BeanPropertyRowMapper class in test class

Tags: java, unit-testing, testing, mockito

Unable to mock BeanPropertyRowMapper data in test class. Tried with different scenario's. Can someone please help me on this.

It is returning null dtoResposne object , but it is returning data in dto object. Here assertion is getting failed while we are comparing with dto with dtoResponse.

Below code is related DaoImpl class

```
public Dto getViewData(String requestId, List<String> errorLsist) {
    String sql = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE id = ?";
        return (Dto) getJdbcTemplate().queryForObject(sql, new Object[] { requestId },
                new BeanPropertyRowMapper(Dto.class));
}

Below code is related to test class 

        String sql = "SELECT * FROM dom.deployment WHERE request_id = ?";
        List<Dto> data = new ArrayList<>();
        Dto dto = new Dto();
        dto.setDecisionFlowGuid(guid);
        data.add(dto);
    Mockito.when(jdbcTemplate.query(
                "SELECT * FROM dom.deployment WHERE request_id = " + requestId,
                new BeanPropertyRowMapper<>(Dto.class))).thenReturn(data);
        Dto dtoResponse = deploymentDaoUtilImpl.getViewData(requestId, errors);
        assertEquals(dto, dtoResponse);

Tried with below scenarios as well.

    Mockito.when((Dto) jdbcTemplate.queryForObject(sql, new Object[] { requestId },
                new BeanPropertyRowMapper<Dto>(Dto.class))).thenReturn(dto);

        Mockito.when((Dto) jdbcTemplate.query(sql, new BeanPropertyRowMapper<>(Dto.class)))
                .thenReturn(dto);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue resolved with below code

```
BeanPropertyRowMapper mapper = new BeanPropertyRowMapper((Dto.class));
    Mockito.when(jdbcTemplate.queryForObject(eq(sql), eq(new Object[] { requestId }), any(BeanPropertyRowMapper.class))).thenReturn(dto);

    Dto dtoResponse = deploymentDaoUtilImpl.getViewData(requestId, errors);
    
    assertEquals(dto, dtoResponse);
```

Answer (score 0):

"jdbcTemplate" must be first created as a Mock (i.e. Mockito.mock) and then the mock injected as a dependency to the caller.

Then your Mockito.when below needs to wrap the *object* you're trying to mock and the function comes after. Review syntax in examples/docs online.

```
   Mockito.when(jdbcTemplate.query(
                "SELECT * FROM dom.deployment WHERE request_id = " + requestId,
                new BeanPropertyRowMapper<>(Dto.class))).
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply...I already mocked JdbcTemplet, but still i am getting response data as null.
Dto dtoResponse = deploymentDaoUtilImpl.getViewData(requestId, errors);
for above i am getting response data as null.
 @Mock
 JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;
like above I mocked  JdbcTemplet